# Image file input not being picked up in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a web page form that needs to select image and upload to a file, but for some reasons i dont know the image is not being detected. I might be missing something. The image folder is was created in the same folder as the application and system. Find the code below

View

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="upload">
        <?php echo $error;?>
        <?php
         echo form_open_multipart('index.php/favoriteMemories/pleasurable');
         echo form_upload('userfile');
         echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
         echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function pleasurable() {

    $config = array(

        'upload_path' => '../images/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
        'max_size' => '1000000',
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
        'encrypt_name' => FALSE
    );
   $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('pleasurable', $error);
    } else {

        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

        $this->load->view('pleasurable');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the image folder writable? Are there any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following,

1. In your controller function you don't need to use the upload code twice.

   $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

its already in the if condition you don't need to call it in else part.

1. Make sure you have loaded the upload library because I didn't see that in controler function, you might load it in constructor or autoload but make sure.

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
2. Make sure you image folder path is correct and writable
3. Check the image type and size you provided in the $config array.

if you see any error message please post it for more help.all the best.

Comment: I have checked all your suggestions and all seems to be in the right order but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i have gone through your code. there is no error in ur code. accept the upload path. 
if you change it to `'upload_path' => 'image/',`
it will save the image in image folder located in root. just make sure the image folder is writable. you can print the upload data and change the folder accordingly. 
use `print_r($this->upload->data());`
to check the uploaded data